# What are these exactly?: Composer, Git and Pyrus

Tags: php, laravel, command-line, frameworks, composer-php

I am trying to start working with PHP frameworks like `Laravel`, `Symphony` or `Zend-framework2`!

But I've understood I'm completely mixed up with different applications I should install before using those frameworks like "Composer", "Git" or "Pyrus".

My BIG question is: What are these things and How should I act with them?

Thanks.

Comment: Just google these names and you will find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) is a dependency manager, if your project uses third party libraries Composer will keep them up to date for you and provide you with an autoloader to use them.

[GIT](https://git-scm.com/) is version control software and effectively lets you back-up your code, provide other people will access to it and provide a log of all changes.

[Pyrus](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/pyrus.about.whatis.php) is a PEAR installer.